# The central idea behind SGD

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, sgd

Pr. Hinton in his popular course on Coursera refers to [the following fact](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-rmsprop-faster-neural-network-learning-62e116fcf29a):

> Rprop doesn’t really work when we have very large datasets and need to perform mini-batch weights updates. Why it doesn’t work with mini-batches? Well, people have tried it, but found it hard to make it work. The reason it doesn’t work is that it violates **the central idea behind stochastic gradient descent**, which is when we have small enough learning rate, it averages the gradients over successive mini-batches. Consider the weight, that gets the gradient 0.1 on nine mini-batches, and the gradient of -0.9 on tenths mini-batch. What we’d like is to those gradients to roughly cancel each other out, so that the stay approximately the same. But it’s not what happens with rprop. With rprop, we increment the weight 9 times and decrement only once, so the weight grows much larger.

As you can see, the central idea behind SGD is that the successive gradients in mini-batches should be averaged. Does any one have any valid formal source for this? is there any justification? I've not encountered to any proof till now.

Comment: Have you drawn conclusions about the answers? If not don't worry.  Just to know if you find problems with them

Comment: Dear @JavierTG not really. I'm looking for free time in my schedule to check your answer, because it demands attention, I need to focus on it. The point is that this question was related to a problem of mine that I have to see its details entirely, and after that I should check your answer.

Comment: Alright @Media, no pressure. Good luck with that problem of yours.

Answer (score 3):

### Influence of the data generating distribution

To see this, first we have to mention that, neither by using Batch gradient descent (using the whole dataset to compute the gradient) nor using mini-batch gradient descent, we are computing the **true** (exact) value of the gradient.

To compute the true value of the gradient we would have to use the set of all possible values of the features, $x$, (and thereby the outputs $y$).

More formally, and refering to the quantity that we want to minimize as the expected value of the per-example loss function ($J(x,y,\theta)$, where $\theta$ are the parameters) w.r.t all the possible $x,y$ values, the true gradient $g$ is given by:
$$g = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\mathbb{E}_{x,y\sim p_{data}}(J(x,y,\theta)) $$
And if we assume [certain conditions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/227065/expectation-of-gradients) We have that:
$$g = \mathbb{E}_{x,y\sim p_{data}}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}J(x,y,\theta)\right) $$

Where $p_{data}$ is the *data generating distribution* (the distribution from which the values of $x$ and $y$ are drawn). However, this data generating distribution is usually unkown. We just know the dataset that we are given.

Because of this, to update the parameters using all the information given (the training set), we instead use the *empirical ditribution* defined by the training data ($\hat{p}_{data}$) which puts a probability of $1/m$ on each of the $m$ samples $(x^{(1)}, y^{(1)}), \,(x^{(2)}, y^{(2)}),\,...\,,(x^{(m)}, y^{(m)})$ of the dataset. So the gradient is approximated by:
$$ \begin{aligned}
\hat{g}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\mathbb{E}_{x,y\sim \hat{p}_{data}}(J(x,y,\theta))\\&=\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{m}J_i(x^{(i)},y^{(i)},\theta)\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}J_i(x^{(i)},y^{(i)},\theta)
\end{aligned}
$$
Ending up with the Batch gradient descent.

### But what happens with mini-batches?

By using mini-bath updates, we are continuously seeing new data (assuming that we compute just one epoch). So in this case, using mini-batches, **we are using the data generating distribution.**

This means that on each mini-batch update, by sampling this data generating distribution, we end up with an *estimation* ($\hat{g}$) of the true gradient ($g$) that is unbiased i.e. $\mathbb{E}_{x,y\sim p_{data}}(\hat{g})=g$. To see this, and considering $\text{s-sized}$ mini-batches:
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}_{x,y\sim p_{data}}(\hat{g})&=\mathbb{E}_{x,y\sim p_{data}}\left(\frac{g^{(1)}+...+g^{(s)}}{s}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{s}(\mathbb{E}_{x,y\sim p_{data}}(g^{(1)}+...+g^{(s)}))\\
&=\frac{1}{s}s\,\,g=g
\end{aligned}
$$
Thereby, making succesive mini-batch updates we would be tending **in average** (as shown by $\mathbb{E}_{x,y\sim p_{data}}(\hat{g})$) to updating our parameters with the true value of the gradient. And this is what I think the authors refer to in the quote of the question.

---

### Great references:

*Deep Learning book, Ian Goodfellow et. al [Chapter 8.1](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/optimization.html)

Answers from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49528/batch-gradient-descent-versus-stochastic-gradient-descent/337738#337738)*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you mind explaining *So in this case, using mini-batches, we are using the data generating distribution.* a bit more?

Comment: I guess this holds just in theory. In action, I guess it is not applicable. What you say is completely logical, but is not applicable for SGD. In SGD, at each step, we have a different point and the derivative is computed in a different location, I mean the parameters are changed with each step of training. However, in the second part of your answer, all the weights are the same. Don't you believe in my claim?

Comment: With that phrase I wanted to express that if we are continuously seeing new data, this can be interpreted as if we are seeing the real distribution of our data. For example, with *online learning* the updates are computed each time a new datapoint arrives, so all the updates are computed based on new (unseen) datapoints that resemble the true distribution of the data $\to$ The gradient computed each time will estimate the *true* gradient and thereby it will be an unbiased estimation.

Comment: If we instead make use of repeated datapoints we are introducing some bias, this is because we will be updating our network based on only our dataset i.e. with each iteration we will be learning only the examples given and not the true data generating distribution. However, as you said, the advantage of *mini-batches* w.r.t. a *batch* may not hold in practice, because more than one epoch may be needed $\to$ we will be seen repeated datapoints in the mini-batches and thereby we will be getting a biased estimation of the gradient.

Comment: So the fact that we are getting an unbiased estimation (considering just one epoch) of the gradient by using mini-batches (or SGD), means that we will be tending *in **average*** to the true value of the gradient (the gradient of the data generating distribution) and this what I think the quote of the question refers to.

Comment: Regarding the last comment, I don't see why the weights of the answer are the same. It's true that with either technique we are using, the weights will change from one iteration to another. The key issue related with the question is that the gradient we are using to make the update of the weights is an estimation of the true gradient with mini-batches (during one epoch).

Answer (score 1):

In a full gradient descent step, the loss function is defined as the average of the loss term at individual sample points. To minimize the loss function, we need to average over the individual gradients.

In the stochastic gradient descent, if there is no bias in selecting the batches, the averaging over the batches would result in a unbiased estimate of the full gradient.

Please take a look at this lecture notes [http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt-F18/scribes/Lecture_24.pdf](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Eryantibs/convexopt-F18/scribes/Lecture_24.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your provided link. Don't you think this is not true due to the fact that the parameters change with each step in SGD?